# How to grant access to current users on VM to copy files to a GCP bucket storage

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage

I have a VM (`vm001`) on Google Cloud and on that I have added some users. Using a user (`user1`) I want to copy a directory to a GCP bucket (`bucket1`). The following is what I do:

```
user1@vm001: gsutil cp -r dir_name gs://bucket1
```

, but I get the following error:

```
[Content-Type=application/octet-stream]...ResumableUploadAbortException: 403 Access denied.
```

I know `user1` does not have access to upload files to `bucket1` and I should use `IAM` to grant permission to it but I do not know how to do it for a user that is on VM. [This video](https://youtu.be/Y2YxhEdCdHg) shows how we can give access using an email but I have not been able to see how we can do it for current users that are already on VM.

**Note**
I have added `user1` using `adduser` on VM and I do not know how to see it on my Google Cloud Console to change its access.

Comment: The permissions are not controlled by `user1`. Permissions (IAM Roles) are managed by the service account assigned to the VM and the `VM Access Scopes` unless you have done something else to authorize the CLI within the VM.

Comment: By default gcloud will use the service account assigned to the VM which in general is the default compute service account so you may need to grant permissions to it or set the needed scopes https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/service-accounts#accesscopesiam

Comment: @John Hanley: so how can I ask that user to upload his files to `bucket1`? can I give `user1` the information of service account to do it?

Comment: @Ferregina Pelona: how can I grant access to all users of a VM to access to a bucket?

Comment: The SA is shared across all users in the VM

Comment: @Ferregina Pelona: suppose I created a SA, then how each user should be able to write into the bucket? Should each user use `gcloud` to authenticate that SA. Or it will be authenticated automatically? Can you provide me with a link of worked example?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes

Comment: @Saeed, do the comments above answer your question? If so, please post it as an answer because it will be very helpful to other community members who have questions similar to yours.

Comment: @Robert G: no it did not. Those comments are some general tips. What I am going to try is to create a service account for my VM and give access to it so that it can write to a bucket to see how it works.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to replicate your error. There are two (2) ways on how to transfer your files from your VM to your GCS bucket.

1. You can either create a new VM or use your existing one. Before finishing your setup, go to **API and identity management > Cloud API access scopes**. Search for **Storage** and set it to **Read Write**.

[image: 1]

2. If you're not sure which access scope to set, you can select **Allow full access to all Cloud APIs**. Make sure that you restrict access by setting the following permissions on your service account under your GCS bucket:

   - Storage Legacy Bucket Owner (`roles/storage.legacyBucketOwner`)
   - Storage Legacy Bucket Writer (`roles/storage.legacyBucketWriter`)

[image: 2]

After that I started my VM and refreshed my GCS bucket and run `gsutil cp -r [directory/name] gs://[bucket-name]` and managed to transfer the files to my GCS bucket.

I followed the steps using this link on [changing the service account and access scopes for an instance](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/access/create-enable-service-accounts-for-instances#changeserviceaccountandscopes). Both steps worked out for me.